# Does Python CGI receive a form value which is set on submit by JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, cgi, submission

I have a HTML form which is submitted to a Python CGI script. From a Java Applet, on submit, additional data is required. Using JQuery, I'm trying to, on submit, attach this data to the form "string" using something like

```
form_data += '&additionalData=' + java_applet_function().getVal() + ';'
$.post('script.cgi', form_data, cb);
```

However, the CGI script apparently does not receive this additional data. While the `java_applet_function` is not the source of error. So my solution now is to, prior to form submission, write the `additionalData` into a hidden HTML form element, from where the CGI script does receive the data.

Is it not possible to do this with JQuery, as I illustrate above? I'm asking, because I believe the HTML hidden input is interfering with some other part of the application.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your scenario, I think "on submit" trigger will do the data append after the submit has occurred (after the form data have already been sent).